# Elasticsearch Filter - AND/OR behaviour

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have this query where I am searching for all documents which match `type: location` and then applying a filter on the result using exact match on `postalCode` and `countryCode` but a prefix on the `address`.

The filter works fine and behaves as an `AND` condition i.e all 3 matches. How can I achieve an `OR` condition in the filter? With the `OR` condition - It should return results even if one filter matches.

**Elasticsearch version - 7.9**

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "location"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "postalCode": "12345"
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "address": "555"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "countryCode": "US"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of bool `should` clause inside the `filter` clause.

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "postalCode": "12345",
  "address": "555",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "type":"location"
}
{
  "postalCode": "9",
  "address": "555",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "type":"location"
}
{
  "postalCode": "9",
  "address": "4",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "type":"location"
}
{
  "postalCode": "9",
  "address": "4",
  "countryCode": "AK",
  "type":"location"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "location"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "postalCode": "12345"
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "address": "555"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "countryCode.keyword": "US"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match":1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65192559",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "postalCode": "9",
          "address": "555",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "type": "location"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65192559",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "postalCode": "12345",
          "address": "555",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "type": "location"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65192559",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "postalCode": "9",
          "address": "4",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "type": "location"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @User0911 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)